# How to loop through javascript object and copy values to new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a javascript object on a page that contains some info.  I need to loop through the object and copy it to another object.

Here is my starting code

```
var p_tag = {};
var new_tag = {};
p_tag.abc='abc';
p_tag.def='def';
p_tag.ghi='ghi';

for (var key in p_tag) {
   if (p_tag.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   console.log(key + "'s favorite fruit is " + p_tag[key]);
   }
}
```

I need to take the values from p_tag and copy them to new_tag as another object.

I may not know what keys are available on each page so looking for something that can go through all available p_tags and copy them to new_tag.

Thanks,

Comment: You can skip the `if (p_tag.hasOwnProperty(key))`. That's like "for each key in this object, check if this object has that key". Just assign it to `new_tag`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign all of the old values to the new values.

```
for (var key in p_tag) {
   if (p_tag.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       console.log(key + "'s favorite fruit is " + p_tag[key]);

       new_tag[key] = p_tag[key];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do a deep copy of an object:

```
var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

So it basically turns your object into a string and then back into an object again with **zero** references to the original.

Comment: Thank you.  This looks simple enough.  Any drawbacks to it vs using what Luka posted below which uses the for loop?

Comment: Yes. if any of those sub items are objects also objects themselves they will still be referenced in Lukas version, in mine all of the references will be broken.